# How to read RCS messages from android device programmatically

Tags: android, sms, messaging, mms

My application basically backup the SMS and MMS to cloud server. I used below URI to retrieve data from database.

> SMS- Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

---

> MMS-Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/");

Few days back while testing my app i noticed some messages(SMS & MMS) are missing while retrieving from SQLite. After doing some research i found that those are RCS (Rich Communication Services) messages. Now my challenge is to read RCS messages(SMS & MMS).
Is there any way to read RCS (Rich Communication Services) messages in Android?
What URI i need to use for read RCS (Rich Communication Services) messages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: It seems like the API [won’t make it after all](https://9to5google.com/2019/07/30/android-rcs-apis-oems-not-third-party-apps/). Work is still happening to it apparently: https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/RCS+(status:open+OR+status:merged). But it won’t be for third-party developers.

---

According to this (https://9to5google.com/2019/02/22/android-q-rcs-api-delay/), now there will be no developer-accessible API for RCS messages until Android R at the earliest.

---

There isn’t a way (short of some vendor-specific API) at the moment, but support for programatically interfacing with RCS is underway if the code commits are any indication of the direction Android is going… https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/849669

The relevant classes are still being implemented, but it looks like you’ll be relying on these (tentatively):

- `RcsParticipant`
- `RcsThread`
- `Rcs1To1Thread` (extends `RcsThread`)
- `RcsGroupThread` (extends `RcsThread`)
- `RcsMessage`
- `RcsIncomingMessage` (extends `RcsMessage`)
- `RcsOutgoingMessage` (extends `RcsMessage`)
- `RcsPart`
- `RcsFileTransferPart` (extends `RcsPart`)
- `RcsLocationPart` (extends `RcsPart`)
- `RcsMultiMediaPart` (extends `RcsPart`)
- `RcsTextPart` (extends `RcsPart`)

This [code](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/860811/5/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/ims/RcsThreadQueryHelper.java) is telling:

```
class RcsThreadQueryHelper {
    static final String ASCENDING = "ASCENDING";
    static final String DESCENDING = "DESCENDING";
    static final String THREAD_ID = "_id";
    static final Uri THREADS_URI = Uri.parse("content://rcs/thread");
    static final Uri PARTICIPANTS_URI = Uri.parse("content://rcs/participant");
    static final String[] THREAD_PROJECTION = new String[]{THREAD_ID};
    static String buildWhereClause(RcsThreadQueryParameters queryParameters) {
        // TODO - implement
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any news on this front? I am already able to receive RCS messages in my SMS app, but I don't know who to send RCS messages. Any clue / link to library or doc?